# How to find x so that $\|A x\| = \|A\| \|x\|$ holds

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

The subbordinance property of matrix-vector multiplication states that
$\|A x\| \le \|A\| \|x\|$
where $\|x\|$ is the norm of vector $x$ and $\|A\|$ is the induced norm of matrix $A$.

Many textbooks provide the proof of this result in theory, but none gives a specific way to find such an $x$ that satisfies the equality $\|Ax\| = \|A\|\|x\|$. For example, given a simple 2x2 matrix $A$, how would one find a 2-D vector $x$ that satisfies the equality?

I am actually interested in the significance of such vector $x$, in addition to its existence in theory.

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $|\langle x, y \rangle| \le \|x\|\|y\|$ becomes an equality if vectors $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent, i.e., $y=cx$, or the angle between $x$ and $y$ is zero. Is there some similar interpretation for $A$ and $x$ that satisfy the equality $\|Ax\|=\|A\|\|x\|$ ?

Comment: Probably a bad idea, but might work for small matrices: Write $A \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ as a function of $x_1$ and $x_2$, and maximize it with the constraint $\|x\|=1$?

Comment: @angryavian : I think OP wants an explicit algorithm. Diagonalization is explicit enough :) See my answer.

Comment: Sorry about my answer, I made an elementary mistake... -_-

Comment: Are you interested in some particular classes of matrix norms? Sometimes, this problem can be relatively easy (matrix $p$-norms for $p=1,2,\infty$). I'm afraid that generally applicable algorithms which take simply a matrix and vector norms as the input might not exist. I would start by looking on resources about computing some interesting norms (e.g., [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~aravindv/matrixpqnorms.pdf)). Most of the algorithms actually compute or estimate such $x$'s.

Answer (score 1):

We have to maximize
$$\|A{\bf x}\|^2=\langle A{\bf x}, A{\bf x}\rangle=\langle A^*A\,{\bf x},{\bf x}\rangle$$
subject to the condition $\|x\|^2=1$. The map $A^*A$ , resp. its matrix $[A^*A]$,  is symmetric positive definite. Therefore there exists an orthonormal basis of ${\mathbb R}^n$ with
$$[A^*A]={\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n),\qquad \lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\ldots\geq\lambda_n\geq0\ .$$
Using this basis we have to maximize
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k x_k^2$$
subject to the condition $x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2=1$. The maximum  obviously has the value $\lambda_1$, and is taken, e.g., at the vector ${\bf e}:=(1,0,\ldots,0)$. It follows that
$$\|A{\bf x}\|=\sqrt{\|A{\bf x}\|^2}\leq\sqrt{\lambda_1}\qquad(\|{\bf x}\|=1)\ ;$$
and on the other hand we have $\|A{\bf e}\|=\sqrt{\lambda_1}$.

When $$A=\left[\matrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}\right]$$ we can write a general unit vector in the form ${\bf x}=(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$, and then have to maximize
$$\eqalign{\|A{\bf x}\|^2&=(a^2+c^2)\cos^2\phi+2(ab+cd)\cos\phi\sin\phi+(b^2+d^2)\sin^2\phi\cr
&={a^2+c^2+b^2+d^2\over2}+{a^2+c^2-b^2-d^2\over2}\cos(2\phi)+(ab+cd)\sin(2\phi)\ .\cr}$$
A well known formula for the amplitude of a trigonometric binomial then gives
$$\lambda_1={a^2+c^2+b^2+d^2\over2}+{1\over2}\sqrt{(a^2+c^2-b^2-d^2)^2+4(ab+cd)^2}\ .$$

Comment: This is still only with respect to the operator norm induced by the Hilbert space norm on $\mathbb C^n$.

Comment: @user161825 I may be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure that's exactly what the OP wants, even if s/he doesn't make the structure of the underlying space explicit.

Answer (score 0):

In general, we have $\|A\|^2=\|A^* A\|$. Furthermore, $A^*A\geq 0$, so there is a unit vector $x$ such that
$$\|Ax\|^2=\langle x,A ^*Ax\rangle=\|A^*A\|=\|A\|^2.$$
In fact, any unit eigenvector $x$ of $A^*A$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $A^*A$ will work.

To clarify, this is with respect to the [operator norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) induced by the 'standard' norm on $\mathbb C^n$ which makes that space into a Hilbert space (in order that we may easily speak of the adjoint of an operator).

Comment: Take
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\3&4\end{matrix}\right)$$
Then $\|A\|^{2}_{1} = 36$ but $\|A^* A\|_{1} = 34$. Are you sure that in general it holds $\|A\|^2=\|A^* A\|$?

Comment: Yes, with respect to the operator norm.

Comment: $\|A\|_1$ is also an operator norm, there is no **the** one and only operator norm. This is true only for the spectral norm.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel AFAIK, when one talks about “the” operator norm of a matrix $\mathbf A$ (or, in general, any continuous linear operator from one vector space to another), its customary interpretation is $$\|\mathbf A\|\equiv\sup\{\|\mathbf A\mathbf x\|\,|\,\|\mathbf x\|\leq1\}.$$ However, you are right in the sense that for a finite-dimensional vector space, all norms on its dual space are equivalent.

Comment: @triple_sec I think the confusion stems from considering different norms on the space $\mathbb C^n$ to begin with. I'm so used to using the 'natural' Hilbert space structure that nothing else occurred to me.

Comment: @triple_sec Yes, but it depends on what the vector norm is. *A* vector norm induces *the* operator norm; therefore, if one does not fix any vector norm, it can be referred to as *an* operator norm. That's not just play with words as what can be true for one (matrix) operator norm, does not need to hold for another. What I say is that this answer is correct *only if* the underlying norm is Euclidean (therefore, for the spectral matrix norm).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel You're right, the OP doesn't state explicitly the norm structure of the underlying vector space (or what this space actually _is_ in the first place), but this vagueness nevertheless doesn't prevent me from being almost sure that s/he means $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$ with the Euclidean norm. If this is the case, then the standard dual-space operator norm seems to me the most natural default choice when we're talking about matrix norms.

Comment: thank you, @AlgebraicPavel, for restoring some sanity into my brain!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who contributed to this discussion. Here is what I got:

Consider

||Ax||^2=<(Ax),(Ax)>=x^*(A^*A)x

if x is the eigenvector corresponding to the greatest eigenvalue of A^*A, which is the spectrum norm ||A||_2 squared, i.e., (A^*A) x=||A||^2 x, then the above becomes

||Ax||^2=x^*||A||^2 x=||A||^2 =(||A|| ||x||)^2

i.e.,

||Ax||=||A|| ||x||

However, this result is only valid for the spectrum norm ||A||_2, the greatest singular value of A (square root of the greatest eigenvalue of A^*A). It would be nice to know how to find such an x for the equality to hold for other forms of norm of A, such as ||A||_1 and ||A||_int, if such methods exist.

Comment: If you have a look on the proof of how $\|A\|_1$ and $\|A\|_{\infty}$ are equated to certain max over row/column sums, you will see how to obtain these $x$'s for these norms as well. It is even easier than for the spectral norm.

Answer (score 0):

For the $2$-norm, pick $x$ to be a singular vector corresponding to the largest singular value of $A$.

The SVD is visualized in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM6Fn.png), which illustrates the fact that $A$ maps a circle to an ellipse (or a sphere to an ellipsoid).
The singular values and singular vectors of $A$ satisfy:
\begin{equation*}
A v_i = \sigma_i u_i.
\end{equation*}
The picture makes it clear that the $2$-norm of $A$ is $\sigma_1$, the largest singular value of $A$.
So
\begin{align*}
\| A v_1 \|_2 &= \| \sigma_1 u_1 \|_2 \\
&= \sigma_1 \\
&= \|A\|_2 \\
&= \|A \|_2 \|v_1\|_2.
\end{align*}
(Note that the singular vectors are all unit vectors.)

This is equivalent to some of the other answers, which don't mention the SVD explicitly.