# What does the equality $\|Ax\|_2=\|A\|_2 \|x\|_2$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, inner-products

We know that the matrix norm $\|A\|_2$ is compatible with the euclidean vector norm $\|x\|_2$, i.e. $\|Ax\|_2 \leq \|A\|_2 \|x\|_2$ for all matrices $A$ and vectors $x$.

I am trying to understand what happens in the case that the equality is obtained, so $\|Ax\|_2=\|A\|_2 \|x\|_2$. Does there exist a (for example) geometric interpretation? Or something like, this equality does only hold for unitary matrices?

I am sorry about the confusion, I will try to clarify by splitting my question:

1. Does $\|Ax\|_2 = \|A\|_2 \|x\|_2$ for all $x$ only hold for special matrices, e.g. unitary matrices?
2. What happens geometrically, if $\|Ax\|_2 = \|A\|_2 \|x\|_2$ for all $x$?
3. What happens geometrically, if $\|Ax\|_2 = \|A\|_2 \|x\|_2$ for a special $x$?
4. What else does $\|Ax\|_2 = \|A\|_2 \|x\|_2$ for all $x$ tell you?

Comment: If $\| A \|_2 =1$, you get an isometry

Comment: this doesn't mean something useful, as it happens every time for some $x$ and arbitrary bounded $A$

Comment: @Masacroso I assume the OP assumes the condition _for all_ $x$?

Comment: @VeryConfused Or perhaps, they wish to know what it says (geometrically) about the relationship between the matrix $A$ and the vector $x$? OP, could you shed some light here?

Comment: @TheoBendit Good point.

Comment: [Relevant:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901169/how-to-find-x-so-that-a-x-a-x-holds?rq=1)

Comment: $\|A \|_2 = \sup_{y \ne0} \frac{\|Ay\|_2}{\|y\|_2}$, so If $\|Ax \|_2 = \|A\|_2 \|x\|_2$ then $\|x\|$ is a vector (up to scalar multiplication) that $\frac{\|A x\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$ being maximum. (Note that up to scalar multiplication, space of the choice for $x$ is a sphere $S^{n-1}$ which is compact, so function $x \mapsto \|Ax \|_2/\|x\|$  always attains a maximum value.)

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable, we can make a diagonal decomposition to analyze the situation.

Comment: I'm sorry. It is related to $A^*A$ which is positive definite, not $A$ itself. Refer to very confused's comment.

Comment: Hello, thank you all for your discussions and I am sorry about the confusion. I hope with the edits the question becomes clear now. Please note, that my focus is not finding a special $x$ that satisfies the equality, but under which conditions the matrix $A$ satisfies the equality for all vectors $x$.

Comment: @dust05 Can you please elaborate a bit more how the diagonalization helps?

Comment: @VeryConfused thank you for link. I am not sure, if the answer given in this post is correct, since it states that $A^TA$ is positive definite, which is not true if the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent

Comment: Let me try a sketch. $A^* A$ (if your setting is in real matrix, you can think of $A^T A$) is diagonalizable with positive real eigenvalues. With the eigendecomposition of vector $x = x_1 + \dots + x_n$ where $x_i$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, we have $|Ax|_2^2 = x^*A^*Ax =x\cdot \left( \sum \lambda_i x_i\right) = \sum \lambda_i |x_i|^2$. So $x$ which maximizes $|Ax|/|x|$ is the direction of eigenvector with the maximal eigenvalue.

Comment: Ok thank you. That clarifies your statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition $\|Ax\|_2 = \|A\|_2 \|x\|_2$ occurs when $x$ is an eigenvector of $\sqrt{A^*A}$ of maximum eigenvalue $\sigma$. Eigenvalues of this matrix are known as singular values of $A$, and the largest such singular value actually turns out to be equal to $\|A\|_2$.

To understand this, you need to understand the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) of a matrix. It decomposes any complex matrix $A$ into $UP$, where $P$ is positive-semidefinite (indeed $P = \sqrt{A^* A}$), and $U$ is orthogonal.

So, what does this polar decomposition actually *do*? The matrix $P$ is positive-semidefinite, which means that it has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors and non-negative real eigenvalues. This means the matrix $P$ will squish or stretch the unit ball in certain directions, by a factor of its eigenvalues (a.k.a. singular values of $A$).

For example, if the singular values of a $2 \times 2$ matrix are $0.5$ and $3$, then you would expect the unit ball to be shrunk along one axis by a factor of $0.5$, but expanded along another axis by a factor of $3$. This will produce an ellipse, with a major axis that is $3/0.5 = 6$ times longer than its minor axis. The trick is, these axes may not be the $x$ and $y$ axes, but you can say with confidence that these axes will be orthogonal to each other.

The matrix $U$ is orthogonal, which makes the transformation $x \mapsto Ux$ an *isometry*, meaning it doesn't mess with distances. Indeed, it doesn't mess with angles either. The matrix $U$ is then applied to our ellipse (note that, in the expression $UPx$, the $U$ matrix is applied *second*, after $P$ is applied!), which rotates or flips this ellipse. Note, it doesn't change the shape of the ellipse, nor does it grow or shrink. After applying $P$, then $U$, the result is the same as applying $A = UP$.

You can think about polar decomposition in much the same way as you think about polar form for complex numbers. The idea is to express a complex number by $re^{i\theta}$, where $r$ is like the positive-semidefinite factor $P$, and $e^{i\theta}$ is like the orthogonal matrix $U$. When you multiply a complex number by $re^{i\theta}$, the $r$ factor stretches or shrinks the complex number by some non-negative factor (well, by $r$, of course!), while the $e^{i\theta}$ performs a rotation (which is a type of isometry).

Anyway, the point is that the positive-semidefinite matrix $P$ is the one that actually determines the *shape* of the unit ball when mapped under $x \mapsto Ax$; the $U$ factor simply determines how it's oriented. That shape determines the operator norm of $A$, because it determines how far out the ellipse pokes out from the unit ball it came from. In our previous example, the ellipse was $3$ times larger on one axis, but half as large in the other. So, along that major axis, a vector grew by a factor of $3$, meaning that $Px = 3x$.

Note that no other vector, aside from $-x$, can grow that much under multiplication by $P$. If they did, they would be on the circle of radius $3$, but since we have an ellipse that isn't a circle, we would expect the circle and the ellipse to touch tangentially at two points: $x$ and $-x$. Every other vector grows, or possibly even shrinks, by a smaller factor.

Applying $U$ doesn't change the length of these vectors, so no matter what, $3$, our maximum singular value, is the greatest growth in length that multiplication by $UP = A$ can possibly produce. This holds in higher dimensions too: the greatest singular value is $\|A\|_2$, and so $\|Ax\|_2 = \|A\|_2\|x\|_2$ holds if and only if $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to maximum singular value $\|A\|_2$.

So, what does it mean when $\|Ax\|_2 = \|A\|_2\|x\|_2$ for all $x$? It means the ellipse we get from mapping the unit circle under $A$ is just a circle of radius $\|A\|_2$. This means that $P = \sqrt{A^*A} = \|A\|_2 I$, i.e. just a scaling map. This means that $A$ is just a scalar times an orthogonal map $U$ (i.e. $A$ only rotates and scales uniformly and non-negatively).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello., thank your for your very detailed answer! It helped me a lot

Comment: @samabu I'm glad. :-) This geometric intuition is why I quite like polar decomposition. I would hear and believe that linear maps would take the unit circle to some kind of ellipse, but I never truly believed it until I understood polar decomposition.

Comment: Yes, that is truly a great way of thinking about it

Answer (score 0):

Taking the example of a diagonalizable matrix, which is the case when $A$ is symmetric, the equality means that the direction of $x$ belongs to the eigenspace of the eigenvalue having the largest modulus.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. Can you please elaborate a bit more what you mean? Are you talking about a special eigenvector or truly all vectors $x$?

Comment: I mean all eigenvectors related to the eigenvalue with the largest modulus.